# how to get list of methods from .java file

Tags: java, reflection

I have a path of a `.java` file in my Java program. I want to get the list of methods that are available in the `.java` file.

For example,
I have a `.java` file at 'C:\temp\Foo.java' as follows:

```
class Foo{
    public int add(int a, int b){ return a+b;}
    public int sub(int a, int b){ return a-b;}
}
```

In my program, I want to get the method names `add` and `sub`.
Is there any java api to achieve the same?
I know that for `.class` file, we can achieve it using Reflection, but is it possible for `.java` file?

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) library.

Here is sample code from their wiki page:

```
public class MethodPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.java");

        CompilationUnit cu;
        try {
            // parse the file
            cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // visit and print the methods names
        new MethodVisitor().visit(cu, null);
    }

    /**
     * Simple visitor implementation for visiting MethodDeclaration nodes. 
     */
    private static class MethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {

        @Override
        public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object arg) {
            // here you can access the attributes of the method.
            // this method will be called for all methods in this 
            // CompilationUnit, including inner class methods
            System.out.println(n.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do MethodVisitor.visit(cu, null); when MethodVisitor is a static class?